# Please how can i position my navbar fixed and transform scale function working

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, less

When position of my navbar fixed with class top, my transform property scale doesn't work on my div element I applied. The only way the hover effect on the box works is when I remove the position on the navbar.

My html:

```html
<header>
   <div class="container">
        <div class="top">
             <div class="logo">Lower Usuma Dam</div>
             <div class="nav">
                  <nav>
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </nav>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS styles:

```css
.box-1:hover,
.box-2:hover,
.box-3:hover,
.box-4:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: 0.9s;
}

.top {
    /* position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 4em;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML)  file?  It is important for me to give you the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `transition` is used on main div not in hover css.
I have created an example. I hope, it will help you. You can ask me for any doubt.

```css
.box-common{width: 50px;height: 50px;background: #fff;border: 3px solid #000;margin: 10px;display: inline-block; transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;}
.box-1:hover,
.box-2:hover,
.box-3:hover,
.box-4:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);   
}
```

```html
<div class="box-common box-1"></div>
<div class="box-common box-2"></div>
<div class="box-common box-3"></div>
<div class="box-common box-4"></div>
```